# How to fill rails form with original content?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am using rails form to update record in database. I have a user form. User can enter value in that. I want to display original value present in that record. User can change that according to requirement or let it be as it is. How to do that in embeded ruby or html ? ...

```
<%= form_with(model: @user1,url: create2_path ,local: true,method: "post" )do |form| %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :password %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :password %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= form.label :email %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :email %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= form.label :accounttype %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :accounttype %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= form.label :phonenumber %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :phonenumber %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= form.label :status %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :status %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit('update') %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need to show us that you have at least attempted to solve the issue.

Comment: Please copy and paste your controller methods for edit and update and your form view into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the user in the controller (`@user`) and either use something like `simple_form` to build the form, or just set input values based on `@user`, like `<input value="<%= @user.name %>">`